# Using case in SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I'm trying to use a `CASE` statement in SQL Server. I'm trying to update the `ProfitUSD` column where in the values fetched from the `Profit` column is multiplied by the conversion rate from the `Rate` column to get the `Profit` in USD (`ProfitUSD` column). Basically, I'm just trying to convert the profit into USD terms by multiplying the respective conversion rate fetched from the `Rate` column.

Any help would be really appreciated :)

The issue here is when I run this I get the following error :

> Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.
>   The statement has been terminated

Code:

```
update dbo.[5 Mins]
set ProfitUSD =
    case
    when Region='AEX 30 Netherlands' then Profit*(select rate from dbo.rates where Region='AEX 30 Netherlands') 
    when Region='ASX Australia' then Profit*(select Rate from dbo.rates where Region='ASX Australia')
    when Region='Athens' then Profit*(select Rate from dbo.rates where Region='Athens')
    when Region='Austria' then Profit*(select Rate from dbo.rates where Region='Austria')
    when Region='Bahrain' then Profit*(select Rate from dbo.rates where Region='Bahrain')
    when Region='Bovespa' then Profit*(select Rate from dbo.rates where Region='Bovespa')
    when Region='Brussels' then Profit*(select Rate from dbo.rates where Region='Brussels')
    when Region='Bucharest' then Profit*(select Rate from dbo.rates where Region='Bucharest')
    when Region='Budapest' then Profit*(select Rate from dbo.rates where Region='Budapest')
    when Region='Bulgaria' then Profit*(select Rate from dbo.rates where Region='Bulgaria')
    when Region='CAC 40' then Profit*(select Rate from dbo.rates where Region='CAC 40')
    when Region='CBOT' then Profit*(select Rate from dbo.rates where Region='CBOT')
    when Region='CME Globex' then Profit*(select Rate from dbo.rates where Region='CME Globex')
    when Region='Comex Metal' then Profit*(select Rate from dbo.rates where Region='Comex Metal')
    when Region='Copanhagen' then Profit*(select Rate from dbo.rates where Region='Copanhagen')
    when Region='DJ Euro Stoxx 50' then Profit*(select Rate from dbo.rates where Region='DJ Euro Stoxx 50')
    when Region='Doha' then Profit*(select Rate from dbo.rates where Region='Doha')
    when Region='Egypt' then Profit*(select Rate from dbo.rates where Region='Egypt')
    when Region='FTSE'  then Profit*(select Rate from dbo.rates where Region='FTSE')
    when Region='FTSE Malaysia' then Profit*(select Rate from dbo.rates where Region='FTSE Malaysia')
    when Region='Hang Seng' then Profit*(select Rate from dbo.rates where Region='Hang Seng')
    when Region='Helsinki' then Profit*(select Rate from dbo.rates where Region='Helsinki')
    when Region='ICE Nybot' then Profit*(select Rate from dbo.rates where Region='ICE Nybot')
    when Region='ICEX Iceland' then Profit*(select Rate from dbo.rates where Region='ICEX Iceland')
    when Region='Istanbul' then Profit*(select Rate from dbo.rates where Region='Istanbul')
    when Region='Johannesberg' then Profit*(select Rate from dbo.rates where Region='Johannesberg')
    when Region='Lima' then Profit*(select Rate from dbo.rates where Region='Lima')
    when Region='Lisbon' then Profit*(select Rate from dbo.rates where Region='Lisbon')
    when Region='Moroccan' then Profit*(select Rate from dbo.rates where Region='Moroccan')
    when Region='Moscow' then Profit*(select Rate from dbo.rates where Region='Moscow')
    when Region='New Zeland NZX' then Profit*(select Rate from dbo.rates where Region='New Zeland NZX')
    when Region='Nigeria 30 Lagos' then Profit*(select Rate from dbo.rates where Region='Nigeria 30 Lagos')
    when Region='Nse All' then Profit*(select Rate from dbo.rates where Region='Nse All')
    when Region='Oman' then Profit*(select Rate from dbo.rates where Region='Oman')
    when Region='Oslo' then Profit*(select Rate from dbo.rates where Region='Oslo')
    when Region='Parague' then Profit*(select Rate from dbo.rates where Region='Parague')
    when Region='Philippines' then Profit*(select Rate from dbo.rates where Region='Philippines')
    when Region='Santiago' then Profit*(select Rate from dbo.rates where Region='Santiago')
    when Region='Saudi' then Profit*(select Rate from dbo.rates where Region='Saudi')
    when Region='Shanghai' then Profit*(select Rate from dbo.rates where Region='Shanghai')
    when Region='Slovenia' then Profit*(select Rate from dbo.rates where Region='Slovenia')
    when Region='Spain' then Profit*(select Rate from dbo.rates where Region='Spain')
    when Region='STI Singapore' then Profit*(select Rate from dbo.rates where Region='STI Singapore')
    when Region='Stockholm' then Profit*(select Rate from dbo.rates where Region='Stockholm')
    when Region='Swiss' then Profit*(select Rate from dbo.rates where Region='Swiss')
    when Region='Toronto' then Profit*(select Rate from dbo.rates where Region='Toronto')
    when Region='TSE Tokyo' then Profit*(select Rate from dbo.rates where Region='TSE Tokyo')
    when Region='Tunisia' then Profit*(select Rate from dbo.rates where Region='Tunisia')
    when Region='Turquise Italy' then Profit*(select Rate from dbo.rates where Region='Turquise Italy')
    when Region='Warsaw' then Profit*(select Rate from dbo.rates where Region='Warsaw')
    when Region='NASDAQ 100' then Profit*(select Rate from dbo.rates where Region='NASDAQ 100')
    when Region='Abu Dhabi' then Profit*(select Rate from dbo.rates where Region='Abu Dhabi')
    when Region='Nordic' then Profit*(select Rate from dbo.rates where Region='Nordic')
    when Region='NYSE All' then Profit*(select Rate from dbo.rates where Region='NYSE All')
    when Region='Seoul' then Profit*(select Rate from dbo.rates where Region='Seoul')
    when Region='Taiwan' then Profit*(select Rate from dbo.rates where Region='Taiwan')
    when Region='Ukraine' then Profit*(select Rate from dbo.rates where Region='Ukraine')
    else ProfitUSD
    end
```

Comment: jeezus, this is really the wrong way to perform this `UPDATE`. First of all, you are getting that error because some of those `(select Rate from dbo.rates where.....)` are returning more than just one row. Now, instead of this gigantic `CASE` expression, you should be doing a `JOIN`

Comment: You must have at least one scenario where there is more than one rate for a region. (Why isn't `Region` unique? Or if it's part of another unique key, why isn't the clause more restrictive?) Also, ugh. Have you considered using a join instead of this heinous `CASE` **expression**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error means that one of your subqueries (the `select rate from dbo.rates where region =`) is returning multiple values. You have two (or more) records for at least one of your region names on that table.

You could (should) be doing this update with a `JOIN` instead of a huge `CASE` statement; what happens when you add a new region?

```
update A set a.profitusd= a.profit*r.rate from dbo.[5 min] A join dbo.rates R on a.region = r.region
```

But that won't solve the problem of duplicates in the `rates` table.

Comment: there are no duplicates in the rates table. there are duplicate values of region in the dbo.5mins :)

Comment: @PrateekDaniels No, there are **definitely** duplicates on the `dbo.Rates` table

Answer (score 7):

This will not fix your problem, but using `update` with `join` will make the query much easier to work with:

```
update f
    set ProfitUSD = Profit * coalesce(Rate, 1.0)
    from dbo.[5 Mins] f left join
         dbo.rates r
         on f.Region = r.Region;
```

Note that this assumes that there are no other regions in the table that might match, but are not mentioned by your `case`.  This seems like a reasonable assumption.

This version will work, in the sense that it will not generate an error.  The problem is that one or more regions have one or more rows in `rates`.  You can find them using:

```
select region, count(*)
from dbo.rates r
group by region
having count(*) > 1;
```

Then fix the data.  Or decide which row you want and fix your logic.  In this version, the logic will be much easier to fix.